# How to install yarn from source?

Tags: ubuntu, github, yarnpkg

I am trying to install the yarn package manager from source onto my Ubuntu machine.

1) Download yarn tarball from **Github Release** page

```
YARN_VERSION=0.17.1
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/releases/download/v${YARN_VERSION}/yarn-v${YARN_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

2) Extract gzipped tar

```
tar -xzf yarn-v${YARN_VERSION}.tar.gz
```

3) Use it

```
cd ./dist/bin/yarn --version
>> 0.17.10
```

So far so good.

**GOAL:** But what is the recommended way to make the `yarn` executable accessible through `/usr/local/bin/yarn --version`?

It seems I need to create a symlink. In that case where is the best place to extract the tarball? Is it `/usr/local/lib/yarn`? How do I create the symlink?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone wanting to build from the bleeding edge, I did the following:

```
cd /my/working/directory
git clone https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn.git
cd yarn
npm install
gulp build
```

Then do as z.ky suggests and `export PATH=$PATH:/my/working/directory/yarn/bin`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on macOS, could you try to adapt it to Ubuntu? Hopefully the commands are close enough/the same.

1. Add the equivalent of this for Ubuntu to your `~/.profile` file (for me it was my `~/.bash_profile` file):

   `export PATH="$PATH:/opt/yarn-v0.23.2/bin"`
2. Then in the terminal, run `source ~/.bash_profile`.
3. Run `yarn --version` to check that it works - you should be able to run this from anywhere now.

I apologise if this isn't 100% correct for you as I can't test it on Ubuntu, but that's how I got it working on macOS.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably install it in the /opt directory like it says in the [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#alternatives-tab).

```
    cd /opt
    wget https://yarnpkg.com/latest.tar.gz
    tar zvxf latest.tar.gz
    # Yarn is now in /opt/yarn-[version]/
```

Then you can export the path like so: `export PATH="$PATH:yarn global bin"`

However if you are running ubuntu you could just use [apt-get](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#linux-tab) or the [nightly builds](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/nightly).

Comment: I didn't get it to run.. that's why I looked into running from source. Either way it is good information that it's best to extract the tar in `/opt`. The following path `/opt/yarn/bin/` seems to be appropriate.

But yes, **apt-get** is infact the easiest solution:

`curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list && apt-get update && apt-get install yarn`

Answer (score -1):

From above comment, after build reference working directory, needs to be in opposite order otherwise env will pick whatever is out of date if already installed: "
For anyone wanting to build from the bleeding edge, I did the following:
cd /my/working/directory
git clone https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn.git
cd yarn
npm install
gulp build
Then do as z.ky suggests and export PATH=$PATH:/my/working/directory/yarn/bin"

Needs to be
PATH=/my/working/directory/yarn/bin:$PATH